# Storing multiple Info in one MySQL column cell

Tags: php, mysql

I have a photo viewer with a comment function for it that everyone can give comment regarding that photo like Facebook.

**1-** My question is that is it possible to have all the comments in one cell of MySQL based on photo id, like:

```
PhotoId | Path      | Date       | Comments
198     | p/car.png | 01/02/2015 | <John, profile link'www.example.com/john', Nice Photo>
                                 | <Charles, profile link'www.example.com/Charles', Nice Photo>
                                 | <Smith, profile link'www.example.com/Smith', Nice Photo>
                                 | <Mark, profile link'www.example.com/Mark', Nice Photo>
                                 | <Max, profile link'www.example.com/Max', Nice Photo>
________________________________________________________________________________________________
199     | p/pen.png | 01/02/2015 | <Mike, profile link'www.example.com/john', Write well>
                                 | <Alex, profile link'www.example.com/Charles', That is your pen>
```

**2-** Is it possible to delete any comment of a specific **PhotoId** by the commentator name from **Comment** column.

If there is any answer for this question then it is good, if not then please guide me through.

Comment: Everything is possible, but let me ask you why you want to do it ? It has no advantages.

Comment: Thats a bad idea, and you should read about database normalization.

Comment: @Viral want to do it because i want safe space and make every thing easy to reach.

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty then what do you suggest.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to do what you ask in **1** - use `serialize` or `json_encode`. It is not possible to do what you ask in **2** without extracting the data and unserializing or decoding it.

It's not good practice to do this. You're better off creating a second table that associates the comments with the PhotoId column of the first table. Better performance and functionality, since you can rely on MySQL to do most of the work for you.

//Edit - Example using Serialize

To enter the information into the database.

```
$data_as_string = serialize(array(
    0 => array('John', "profile link'www.example.com/john'", 'Nice Photo'),
    1 => array('Charles', "profile link'www.example.com/Charles'", 'Nice Photo'),
    2 => array('Smith', "profile link'www.example.com/Smith'", 'Nice Photo'),
    3 => array('Mark', "profile link'www.example.com/Mark'", 'Nice Photo'),
    4 => array('Max', "profile link'www.example.com/Max'", 'Nice Photo')
);
```

To retrieve it as an array.

```
$data_as_array = unserialize($row['comments']);
```

Comment: Thanks, what do you mean by **serialize**, can you provide me an example

Answer (score 0):

All are possible.

Suggestions

- make it two tables. One for storing photos and one for comments you can link the photos and comments using a foreign key.
- You should keep commentator name in comments table so that you can delete the comments by commentator name

Comment: then it would a lots of table

Comment: Do you have restriction on number tables used?

Comment: no, but pretend i have 1000 photos and each photo has 20 comment from different user the it would be 20000 tables and i think it makes the database slow

Comment: You got it wrong, let me explain you have table photos with columns photo_id,photo_name,photo_path and you have table comments with column comment_id, photo_id,commentor_name,comment. So there will no multiple tables created for each comment.  Like in your example you have 20 photos and comments for these photos will 20000 rows in comments table. You can refer photo comment using comment->photo_id

Comment: Good, what about 1000000 comment won't it take time to search and show the result

Comment: You should index comment table with frequent search queried columns. If you search using the primary key (comment_id) then it won't be slow

Comment: Can you give me an example of indexing or a reference.